# EF Database First context as datasource to DataGrid. How to limit columns?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, datagrid

Using Entity Framework v6.13 with a database first approach. I have an ASP.NET web forms application that makes use of the DataGrid control. I am binding as such in the code behind.

```
mydataGrd.DataSource = dbContext.GetCustomers.ToList<Customer>();
mydataGrd.DataBind();
```

The problem is I only want to display some of the properties of the customer and not all. I thought by just listing the columns I wanted as bound columns it wold work but instead I get an error.

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="mydataGrd" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" />
  </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

Here is the error I get ...

```
Parser Error Message: System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridColumnCollection must have items of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridColumn'. 'asp:BoundField' is of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `BoundColumn`

```
<asp:DataGrid  ID="mydataGrd" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="LastName" />
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="FirstName" />
  </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

good example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I beleive that asp:boundfield is for asp:GridView controls, however it's been a while.